# different batch size according to table column in database

Tags: anylogic

I am new to anylogic. I am trying to model a source with arrival dates and multiple agents per arrival and had been imported successfully from a table from database. it works well until i am trying to batch the units per arrival and set the batch size from the same column of multiple agents per arrival. it doesn't work well. why this happening as there is no error occurs but when i try to run the model doesn't open. what is the wrong and how i can do it? thanks in advance.[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Jav.png), [batch block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7PCa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oui3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement in the Batch block is not sufficient: you are always just querying the first entry in `shipments_data.amount`:
[image]

You need to add a "Choice condition" just below it such that you specify which row from `shipments_data` to use for the `amount` value.

(Think about the table: How would an agent in the `Batch` block know which `amount` to use without a specific condition?)

If you cannot find a good condition, you probably should store the `amount` value as a parameter in your `MyAgent` type upfront in the `Source` block and use the parameter in the "Batch size" field instead, not query the dbase

Comment: thanks for your reply Ben., i have done this before created a parameter called it a an amount  in my agent   and gone no where but error Description: amount cannot be resolved to a variable. , excuse my lack of experience.

Comment: if i have an id parameter i tried to use it as a condition in condition where choice condition is amount equals agent.id , it doesn't work also.

Comment: Please open a new issue if you struggle with a new problem, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow